# Changing elements ids with jquery and regex

Tags: jquery, regex

With following code

```
<div id="family">
  <input type="text" id="test_0_0"/>
 <input type="text" id="hello_0_0"/>

</div>
 <div id="family1">

  </div>
```

Using Jquery and regex, i want to copy same html inside family1 from family div but with id's as

```
<input type="text" id="test_1_0"/>
<input type="text" id="hello_1_0"/>
```

I tried with this but does not work

```
function renumber(){
    var content=$('#family').html();
    var pattern = new RegExp("_0","g");
    var final=content.replace(pattern,"_1");
    $('#family1').html(final);
}
```

Comment: Is this something that is to be done repeatedly?  Is the second zero ever supposed to increment to 1?  Under what circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function renumber(){
    var content=$('#family').html();
    var pattern = new RegExp("(\\w)_0", "g");
    var final=content.replace(pattern,"$1_1");
    $('#family1').html(final);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5njU2/

Answer (score 0):

You could sure simplify this to not needing regex at all by adding a `data-` attribute to each `family` element. You aren't using any classes which is likely a mistake also since you could do something like this to manage all the incrementation:

```
<div class="family" data-familyID="0">
  <input type="text" class="test"/>
   <input type="text" class="hello"/>
</div>
```

JS to create a new "family" element from existing one

```
var lastFamily= $('.family').last()
var newFamily =lastFamily.clone();
var newFamilyID=newFamily.data('familyID')+1;
 /* update familyID and reset inputs*/
 newFamily.data('familyID', newFamilyID).find('input').val('').insertafter(lastFamily);
```

JS to handle change of an input and get current family ID of input `family`

```
/* delegate to body to account for dynamicly added elements*/
$('body').on('change', '.family input', function(){
    var val=$(this).val(), className=$(this).attr('class'), familyID=$(this).closest('.family').data('familyID');
    alert( className +' #'+familyID+' value='+val);
})
```